# Running VMs in a background on VMWare Workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am trying to run a VM on VMWare Workstation in sort of 'background' mode, basically I want to start it without a console and connect to it via ssh only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 42):

Yes it is possible. You can do this with the "vmrun" command using the "nogui" option:

```
 vmrun -T ws start /export/vmware/rh5/server.vmx nogui
```

The VM will then come up without starting the Workstation GUI and you can ssh to it.

If your host os is Windows change the path to:

```
vmrun -T ws start C:\export\vmware\rh5\server.vmx nogui
```

Comment: This worked for me!, this should be the correct Answer!

Comment: FYI, I had to download VMware VIX to get the vmrun command

Comment: What does `-T ws` do?

Comment: @logicor `-T ws` specifies that the host is Workstation. The other options are fusion or player.

Answer (score 8):

You can start the VM in workstation and then you simply close the tab that it's open on.  Workstation will ask you if you want to power off, suspend, or background that virtual machine.

Comment: interesting...gotta try that!

Comment: didn't work for me: it just closed and suspended the vm.

Comment: It works fine! Thanks! Much more faster than command line solution... You can close main GUI after closing tab. It will "sit" in the system tray.